# PHP start new row

Tags: php, mysql

I have wrote a script to show data from a `MySql DB`

```
   <div class="row">
   <?
     for ($i = 1; $i <= mysql_num_rows($result41); $i++)
     {
       echo"        <div class='col-md-3 col-sm-6'>
                    <div class='single-shop-product'>
                        <div class='product-upper'>

                    </div>
                </div>    
        ";  
    }    
    if ($i % 4 == 4) {
        echo "</div><div class='row'>"; // it's time no move to next row
    }
```

After 4 products have been shown I want to start a new row, I have added

> if ($i % 4 == 4)

into the script thinking this would work, however it doesn't, can anyone help?

Comment: Modulo `% 4` can never return 4. The remainder is always between 0 and 3 then.

Comment: So what should the code be?

Comment: Modulo returns the rest which cannot be further divided. I.e. 10 % 3 = 1, because 1 would be the rest. Hope this helps you to understand modulo better.

Comment: You want `$i % 4 == 0`, that will tell you if the current value is evenly divisible by 4 (remainder = 0).

Comment: Note that after the `for` loop `$i` is `mysql_num_rows($result41) + 1`. Probably not what you want. Starting from 0, `for ($i=0 ; $i < ...` would solve that (and  is generally a better approach).

Answer (score 3):

Replace your line of code with this.

```
 if ($i % 4 == 0)
 {
  //Do something
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You want $i % 4 == 0, that will tell you if the current value is evenly divisible by 4 (remainder = 0).